# Logstash in reading files issues

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have written a logstash conf file to read through logs. It run fine when I specify the log path to a single file. However, if I made it to *.log, it can't run any files. How can I resolve it?

Here is the one which works.

```
input{
    stdin{}
    file{
        type => "txt"
        path => "C:\HA\accesslog\trial.log"
        start_position => "beginning"
    }
}
filter{
    grok{
    match => {"message" => ["%{IP:ClientAddr}%{SPACE}%{NOTSPACE:access_date}%{SPACE}%{TIME:access_time}%{SPACE}%{NOTSPACE:VirtualHost}%{SPACE}%{WORD:cs-method}%{SPACE}%{PATH:cs-uri-stem}%{SPACE}%{PROG:Protocol}%{SPACE}%{NUMBER:sc-status}%{SPACE}%{NUMBER:bytes}%{SPACE}%{NOTSPACE:RequestedSessionId}%{SPACE}%{PROG:Ecid}%{SPACE}%{NUMBER:ThreadId}%{SPACE}%{NUMBER:EndTs}%{SPACE}%{NUMBER:time-taken}"]}
        }
    if "_grokparsefailure" in [tags] {
        drop { }
    }   
}
output{
    elasticsearch { 
        hosts => ["localhost:9200"] 
        index => "logstash-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
        template_overwrite => true
    }
    stdout { codec => rubydebug }   
}
```

When I change path to

> path => "C:\HA\accesslog\*.log"

It could not work.

Comment: it should be C:\HA\accesslog\\*.log

Comment: Sorry, it is just my typo in the question. I did put \ in my conf file.

Comment: There isn't any error shown, just when the pipeline started, it does not give out any output.

Comment: I have make trial and error and turn out suddenly realized that when I replace the backslash with forwardslash, the problem can then be solved.